# 10 clients requests for a Servlet.How many servlet instances are created

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Suppose 10 clients requests for a Servlet. How many servlet instances are created? Also will it create any concurrency modification problem if each instance is trying to make changes? Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only one instance of servlet exist (per classloader) , and each request will be served on its own thread

So is there any thing that is shared amongst requests you need to manage synchronization

Comment: Hi , each request will be served on its own thread. Could you please explain.

Comment: if you make GET to servlet it will invoke `doGet()` for your request, but if you make another request there would be another thread created

Comment: Will this servlet service each thread requests one by one.ie one thread will wait for the other to be serviced.

Comment: @user1281029: No, the point of the threads is that they run in parallel.

Comment: So if we want to make that JSP threadsafe, How will we do it.

Comment: @JigarJoshi that is only true for HttpServlets. The service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) is what is actually called by a servlet container such as tomcat.

Comment: If there is any data that is shared amongst each request(thread) and if it needs to be synchronized than manage it with synchronization(synchronized method, data structure), For example you have a `List` as a member variable of Servlet Class and in each request you are operating on it then you need to make it synchronized list

Comment: one more doubt, can I use synchronized in a JSP.

Comment: Why do you need to use synchronized in jsp ?

Comment: Hi, For making sure that my variables value is not changed concurrently.

Comment: how would it change concurrently in a jsp ?

Comment: Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @user1281029 The idea is not to have such variables, rather than synchronize. It's a server, you want to achieve maximum concurrency. Variables concerned with the request should be stored as request attributes; variables concernd with the session should be stored as session attributes; and as many variables as possible should be method-local.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet is instanciated as singleton in servlet container, thats why we can't declare global variables in it.

Comment: 'Mustn't' would be more accurate than 'can't'.

Comment: Sometimes it is intended to share the variables across the threads.

Comment: see some   alternatives to do it  here http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_01.htm