# How many instances are created for a HTTP servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am going through the book for ["Java Web Services: Up and Running, 2nd Edition"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029571.do) and came across a statement that says:

> A web server such as Tomcat can instantiate arbitrarily many instances
>   of a servlet, although the number is typically small (e.g., 1 through
>   4). The web server itself makes the decision.

So it means if I create a servlet then the server can create more than 1 instance but this is in contradiction to the explanation given in many posts for example if I check in this post : "[10 clients requests for a Servlet.How many servlet instances are created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577414/10-clients-requests-for-a-servlet-how-many-servlet-instances-are-created)" then it clearly states that:

> Only one instance of servlet exist (per classloader) , and each
>   request will be served on its own thread

So please help me in understanding this, does a server can create more than 1 instance for a servlet?

Comment: For some reason, I made an assumption that each request had its own instance, so I was making use of class fields assuming they were unique to each request. This led to a bug that was very confusing until I realized the same instance was being reused for multiple requests 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) states

> **For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
>   the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet
>   declaration.** However, for a servlet  implementing the
>   `SingleThreadModel` interface, **the servlet container may  instantiate
>   multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and serialize
>   requests to a particular instance.**
>
> In the case where a servlet was deployed as part of an application
>   marked in the  deployment descriptor as distributable, a container may
>   have only one instance per  servlet declaration per Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM). However, if the servlet in a  distributable
>   application implements the `SingleThreadModel` interface, the container 
>   may instantiate multiple instances of that servlet in each JVM of the
>   container.

So it depends how you are deployed.

As suggested in the comments, [`SingleThreadModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) has been deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

by default servlets are intrinsic multithreaded. so only single instance be created and will be accessed by multiple threads.